# How to abstract away command code in custom django commands

Tags: python, django

I'm writing custom django commands under my apps `management/commands` directory. At the moment I have 6 different files in that directory. Each file has a different command that solves a unique need. However, there are some utilities that are common to all of them. What is the best way to abstract away this common code?

Below is an example:

*`load_colors`*

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
   def handle(self, *args, **options)
      ....code unique to colors
   def check_validity(self, color)
      ....#code common to both shades and colors
```

*`load_shades`*

```
 class Command(BaseCommand):
   def handle(self, *args, **options)
      ....#code unique to shades
   def check_validity(self, color)
      ....#code common to both shades and colors
```

Comment: Maybe you should keep the common code in a .py file and import that wherever you want to use. That way you don't repeat your code. just call the existing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the management/commands folder create the file _private.py:

```
#_private.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class SharedCommand(BaseCommand):
   def check_validity(self, color):
      ...
```

The in other files import this file and inherit SharedCommand:

```
# command01.py
from ._private import *

class Command(SharedCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        ...
```